# How to concatenate different sized videos and then overlay with transparency on a background in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, alpha-channel

I have multiple videos that are different sized, and I needed to concatenate them and then put the finished concatenated result on top of a 1080p background. However, the only way I can currently do this is by padding the individual clips so they are the same size before i concat them. I tried making the padding #00000000@0.0 so it has alpha, but when I move onto the overlay command, and then output it I see black padding. How do I get alpha padding and keep the alpha for the overlay process?

I'm using php to form the pad string command and the concatenate command for reasons not related to this question:

```
//  echo shell_exec("$ffmpeg $inputStringForConcat -i background2_correctproperties.mov -y -filter_complex '$padString $inputPadString concat=n=$concateNvalue:v=1:a=0 [conc],[$inputIndexOfBackground:v][conc]overlay=shortest=1' -c:v qtrle -qscale 0 concatenated_$time.mov 2>&1");
```

Comment: Show entire command and console output.

Comment: added it to the question